# Sanitize codes injection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a comment box and insert the value to mysql using ajax. Same time I append the entered comment with jQuery to the same page. The problem is if the entered text is some JavaScript code, like

```
<script>alert('hello');</script>
```

it shows the alert. In my database I sanitize these code but since I append it in client side I need to display the entered text like it is.

Well I use,

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Any immediate help, please?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet HTML encodes string to:

```
"&lt;div&gt;Here is an HTML&lt;/div"


$("p").text("<div>Here is an HTML</div").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method!

```
str.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
str.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```